Ignore peer dependency problems of a specific npm dependency (after ERESOLVE)
Context
I just did some dependency cleanup of my repo after installing a new angular version (18).
I had the famous ERESOLVE could not resolve error because of peer dependencies.
For most of the problematic dependencies I could just update them but one dependency simply has no updated version.
To make it more specific: ngx-resize needs angular v14-16 (I use angular 18 now)
> npm info ngx-resize peerDependencies
{
   '@angular/common': '^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0',
   '@angular/core': '^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0'
}

I have learned that I could use --legacy-peer-dep, but I think that it makes total sense that npm helps me to recognize such problems and don't want to use this flag for the rest of my repos life.
What are my options?
Let's say it is not an option to get rid of the problematic dependency (it could be in this case but maybe it will not be possible in a future case)
If I understand npm overrides correctly this overrides the peer dependency rules of all my dependencies for a specific package.
For example I define
"overrides": {
    "@angular/*": "$@angular/common"
}

This basically means: even if there are different packages disagreeing on the to-be-installed version of a package that starts with '@angular/', always install the version that the @angular/common package has.
This solves my dependency problem with ngx-resize for now, as its wish for the older angular version gets overruled, but if I update angular in the future, I would not see any new errors if other dependencies become a problem. If those other dependencies provide an update I would prefere to recognize the problem.
My question
Instead of overriding every (in this case angular-)version discussion between dependencies, I would love to ignore the problem of the specific package ngx-resize in this case. So that new problems get recognized again.
Is there any way to do this?
